# Spark: Extaract domain from email address in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a difficulty in extracting email domains. I have below dataframe.

```
+---+----------------+
|id |email           |
+---+----------------+
|1  |ii@koko.com     |
|2  |lol@fsa.org     |
|3  |kokojambo@mon.eu|
+---+----------------+
```

Now I want to have a new field for domains which I'll get:

```
+---+----------------+------+
|id |email           |domain|
+---+----------------+------+
|1  |ii@koko.com     |koko  |
|2  |lol@fsa.org     |fsa   |
|3  |kokojambo@mon.eu|mon   |
+---+----------------+------+
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
val test = df_short.withColumn("email", split($"email", "@."))
```

But got a false output. Can anybody direct me better?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you posted the wrong output or error message that you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use inbuilt `regexp_extract` function to get your domain name from email address.

```
//create an example dataframe
val df = Seq((1, "ii@koko.com"),
  (2, "lol@fsa.org"),
  (3, "kokojambo@mon.eu"))
  .toDF("id", "email")

//original dataframe
df.show(false)
//output
//    +---+----------------+
//    |id |email           |
//    +---+----------------+
//    |1  |ii@koko.com     |
//    |2  |lol@fsa.org     |
//    |3  |kokojambo@mon.eu|
//    +---+----------------+

//using regex get the domain name
df.withColumn("domain",
  regexp_extract($"email", "(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\\.)", 0))
  .show(false)

//output
//    +---+----------------+------+
//    |id |email           |domain|
//    +---+----------------+------+
//    |1  |ii@koko.com     |koko  |
//    |2  |lol@fsa.org     |fsa   |
//    |3  |kokojambo@mon.eu|mon   |
//    +---+----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    df.withColumn("domain",  split(split(df.col("email"),"@")(1),"\\.")(0)).show
```

Sample Input:

```
+---------------+
|          email|
+---------------+
|manoj@gmail.com|
|      abc@ac.in|
+---------------+
```

Sample Output:

```
+---------------+------+
|          email|domain|
+---------------+------+
|manoj@gmail.com| gmail|
|      abc@ac.in|    ac|
+---------------+------+
```

Comment: This wouldn't work always. When an email id has a "." in the username for eg: abc.def@gmail.com "def" gets returned as domain

Comment: @ThReSholD, Could you please first check the logic? Is it working or not?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it didn't work for me. When I gave email="abc.def@gmail.com" and tried extracting the domain using df.withColumn("domain",  split(df.col("email"),"[@.]")(1)).show it returned "def" as domain instead of "gmail"